# How to use DLLIMPORT in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, c++, macos, xamarin

I have a console project for mac in Xamarin and want to use c++ functions from external library. But unfortunately when I try to use DLLIMPORT like this (c#):

```
[DllImport('path to the library')]
static extern double sum(double x, double y);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine(sum(2,2));
}
```

I get *System.DLLNotFoundException*. However it works with system libraries:

```
[DllImport("/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib")]
static extern IntPtr dlopen(string path, int mode);
```

**Here is all my code**:

1) *main.cpp* (from lib.dylib library):

```
extern "C" double sum(double x, double y) {
   return x + y;
}
```

2) *Program.cs* (from Xamarin C# Project):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Project {
   class MainClass {
      [DLLImport("/full/path/to/lib.dylib")]
      static extern double sum(double x, double y);

      public static void Main(string[] args) {
         Console.WriteLine(sum(2,2));
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

I use XCode to create the library (.dylib) but not sure if I do everything right.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/native-interop#accessing-c-dylibs

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what was wrong.
The way I reference the library in c# is OK. The problem is that I build library incorrectly. Let me explain.

To create the library I use XCode Library Project for Mac OS (framework : None (Plain C/C++ Library)):

[press here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f05XM.jpg)

That means my "Architectures" panel in the "Build Settings" tab by default looks like this:

[press here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WydWV.png)

Pay attention to the highlighted properties. They are important.
So if I leave it as it is and just press cmd+B (build) I WILL get a library (.dylib file). But if I go to the terminal and inspect this library with *lipo* I will get:

```
lipo -info path/to/the/library.dylib
Non-fat file: path/to/the/library.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

But if I do the same to the /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib library (or any other system .dylib library) the output will be different:

```
lipo -info /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib are: x86_64 i386
```

It's easy to guess that I want to see the same when I inspect my own library. To fix it go back to the "Architectures" panel and do following:

1) Check your "Valid architectures" property. Its value must be "i386 x86_64" (without quotes).

2) For "Build Active Architectures Only" property choose "No". By now your "Architectures" panel must look like this:

[press here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UvL1.jpg)

3) Press on the "Architectures" property. Choose "Other..." as value and in the opened window type:

```
${ARCHS_STANDARD}
x86_64
i386
```

[press here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgtBu.jpg)

As a result your "Architectures" panel must look like this:

[press here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkXNH.jpg)

That's all! Now you can build your library! If you inspect it with *lipo* now you will get:

```
lipo -info /path/to/your/library.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: /path/to/your/library.dylib are: x86_64 i386
```

I'm not sure what the difference but oddly it solves the problem. Now I can call my c++ functions from c#.

Does anyone know what happens?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to use methods from a DLL dependency is by adding it to the project's dependencies. To do that, do the following:

1. Right click on the namespace you want to add the dependency to, then go to Add -> "Reference...";
2. The Reference Manager will open. Click on "Browse..." and find your DLL file.
3. Click "OK" and your DLL will be added as a dependency to your project.

To use its methods inside a C# file, use the "using" syntax on top of the file, for example: `using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering;`. After that, code compiled inside the DLL will be available for you to use in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mateus! Unfortunately this does't work because Xamarin doesn't allow to choose my ".dylib" library like this. Maybe there are different ways?

Comment: The .dylib stands for "dynamic library", which is the same concept to Windows .dll. Was this file generated by you? If so, you could probably recompile it as a .dll so you could import it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just saw you said you compiled it in XCode. If you chose to take this path, you will need to cross compile your program from Mac format to Windows format. That is possible but there should be an easier alternative. My guess would be that if you're running Visual Studio on a Mac, it would just accept a ".dylib" file as it accepts ".dll" on Windows.